# How to display HTML5 convert of a PDF on page without using an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, seo

I do not want to embed the PDF directly as the PDF is itself indexed by Google, and is returned directly in Google search results (If the PDF is displayed on page I can benefit from advertising clicks).

As suggested elsewhere on StackOverflow I have used this conversion tool:

http://www.idrsolutions.com/example_conversions/

However the output from here in the Iframe is not indexed by Google.

Here is an example of the output I desire:

http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/132858/jaguar-s-type.html

How can I replicate this Functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee that we will.

From here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en

Speculating, what this probably means is that the content should be on the same domain (to ensure it's your content) and only iframed once or a small number of times (so that multiple pages cannot gain credit for the same piece of content).

Did you follow the above ideas and give Google enough time to index the content?

For disclosure, I am a developer at IDRsolutions.

We do have customers who are iframing converted content and having it indexed by Google. You might like to try the singlefile mode that puts all pages into one file so Google is able to easily index content on all of the pages.

If you have any questions specific to the conversion, there are support forums here: http://support.idrsolutions.com/forums/forum/pdf-conversion-forum/